# 3D plot in python with values on coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have some value at every on x,y,z coordinate, and x,y,z coordinated are not in grid pattern.i want to plot them as matshow or imshow, but unable to do that.

I m doing a time iteration in which these values at these coordinates are changing during iteration, so I want to plot them.

A 3D plot showing values

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: _"these coordinates are changing, but the coordinates are the same"_ I am unable to understand your statement, could you please rephrase it? (you can [edit] your question)